# How to install Windows 8.1 Store App for all users

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app

I am the admin on a family 8.1 PC.  My children are "child" users.  Today I installed the "Fresh Paint" under my account but when the children log in they don't see it as an app.  Instead the app store says they need me a permission that is not specified.

Why is the app not visible as already installed for the children accounts?
What permission do I need to adjust to allow them to download it again from the store?

Comment: I assume these are user accounts limited by parental guidance permissions?

Comment: yes they are control by Microsoft's child safety.

Comment: Did you install the application as an Administrator ( but not the default account )